# How to get input box content in kivy application

Tags: python

I'm writing a kivy app that lets the user enter and store content, but I've searched the web and can't find a solution

This is the python program

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.graphics import Line, Color
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', False)
from kivy.core.window import Window
Window.size = (450, 800)

class DrawCanvasWidget(Widget):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

class PaintApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.draw_canvas_widget = DrawCanvasWidget()
    
        return self.draw_canvas_widget  # 返回root控件

if __name__ == "__main__":
    PaintApp().run()
```

This is the kv program

```
<DrawCanvasWidget>
orientation: "vertical"
canvas.before:
    Color:
        rgba: [1,1,1,1]
    Rectangle:  
        pos: self.pos
        size: self.size
TextInput:
    multiline:False
    font_size:20
    pos:75,450
    size:300,40
    allow_copy:False
    cursor_color:[0,1,0,1]
Button:
    text:'ok'
    bold:10
    size_hint:None,None
    size:100,50
    pos:180,380
```

I want to let the user save the content of the input box after pressing the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the basic idea. Create a function in the draw canvas widget and pass the text of the text input by using the id tag.

```
<DrawCanvasWidget>
      orientation: "vertical"
          canvas.before:
              Color:
                  rgba: [1,1,1,1]
              Rectangle:  
                  pos: self.pos
                  size: self.size
          TextInput:
              id: text_input                
              multiline:False
              font_size:20
              pos:75,450
              size:300,40
              allow_copy:False
              cursor_color:[0,1,0,1]
          Button:
              text:'ok'
              bold:10
              size_hint:None,None
              size:100,50
              pos:180,380
              on_release: root.submit(text_input.text)   


class DrawCanvasWidget(Widget):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def submit(self, text_input):
        print(text_input)
        # Should print whatever is in the textinput to the terminal
        # Here you can save it to your database or do anything with the input.
```